# Add log4net appender programmatically, but layout does not work

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I have following code to add a rolling file appender to log4net.

```
        ILog myLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("Audit");

        var auditAppender = new RollingFileAppender()
        {
            Name = "AuditAppender",
            File = this.fullyQualifiedFileName,
            DatePattern = "yyyyMMdd",
            RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date,
            AppendToFile = true,
            Layout = new PatternLayout()
            {
                ConversionPattern = "%newline %date %-5level %newline%message%newline",
            },
        };

        auditAppender.ActivateOptions();

        log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger l = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)myLogger.Logger;
        l.AddAppender(auditAppender);
        l.Repository.Configured = true;

        myLogger.Info(message);
```

But the result does not seem to follow my `ConversionPattern` at all. Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very, very close ;-)

The only thing you missed is you need to call `PatternLayout.ActivateOptions` as well:

```
var auditAppender = new RollingFileAppender()
{
    // snip
}

((PatternLayout)auditAppender.Layout).ActivateOptions();
auditAppender.ActivateOptions();
```